# Resource Recommendation for Quantum Information Theory especially entanglement in quantum field theory

Tags: quantum-field-theory, quantum-information, quantum-entanglement

I am trying to start learning quantum information from a theoretical point of view not involving aspects of quantum computing. The main thing that I want to understand is entanglement from both a quantum field theoretic point and an information theory viewpoint.